# Encryption Program Error if the letter is Z

Tags: encryption, vbscript

I am trying to encrypt a message but if I use the letter Z it gives an error. This is the error (it's Dutch):

[image: Ongeldige procedureaanroup of ongeldig argument (invalid procedure call or argument)]

```vb
Set x = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
mySecret = InputBox("The code")
mySecret = StrReverse(mySecret)
x.Run "%windir%\notepad"
WScript.Sleep 1000 
x.SendKeys encode(mySecret)
Function encode(s) 
    For i = 1 To Len(s) 
        newtxt = Mid(s, i, 1)
        newtxt = Chr(Asc(newtxt)+3)   
        coded = coded & newtxt 
    Next 
    encode = coded 
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The [docs for SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.84).aspx) state:

> Brackets "[ ]" have no special meaning when used with SendKeys, but
>   you must enclose them within braces to accommodate applications that
>   do give them a special meaning (for dynamic data exchange (DDE) for
>   example).

Your encoding method:

```
>> WScript.Echo Chr(Asc("Z") + 3)
>> WScript.Echo Chr(Asc("X") + 3)
>>
]
[
>>
```

generates brackets for Z and X.

**After further testing:**

The nasty letters are not (uppercase) X ([) and Z (]) but their lowercase cousins:

docs:

> To send brace characters, send the string argument "{{}" for the left
>   brace and "{}}" for the right one.

evidence:

```
>> set x = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
>> x.sendkeys Chr(Asc("z") + 3)
>>
Error Number:       5
Error Description:  Invalid procedure call or argument
>> x.sendkeys Chr(Asc("x") + 3)
>>
Error Number:       5
Error Description:  Invalid procedure call or argument
>>
```

Comment: So how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Don't use .SendKeys/Notepad for IO.